# Form Validation - Radio Loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to validate a section of my form using JS.  The user should click one of 3 radio buttons.  If none of them are selected, the value of a certain variable ($planSelectValid) should be false.   If the user clicks one of the radios, it should switch the value to true.   From this, I can later check the variable to ascertain whether the submit button should be active.

I have spent a good amount of time on this and I cannot seem to get this to work correctly.  I have to admit that I am still rather green when it comes to JS.  What am I missing/doing-wrong? Any help with this is most appreciated :)

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
HTML
<div class="socPlanRadios">
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="socPlan" value="Plan 1" id="plan1">
        <label for="plan1"><b>Plan 1</b></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="socPlan" value="Plan 2" id="plan2">
        <label for="plan2"><b>Plan 2</b></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="radio" name="socPlan" value="Plan 3" id="plan3">
        <label for="plan2"><b>Plan 3</b></label>
    </p>

</div>

JS
<script>
    $planSelectValid = false;

    function ValidateRadioButtons() {  //Function for Validating If Radio Button isselected

    $('.socPlanRadios').find('radio').each(function () {  //LoopingthroughradioButtons
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $planSelectValid = true; 
        }
    });

    if ($planSelectValid = true) {
        alert("Validation Passed");
      } else {
        alert("Please select a Radio Button");
      }
    }

    $('.socPlanRadios').find('radio').blur(ValidateRadioButtons);
</script>
```

Comment: $('.socPlanRadios').find('radio') is not right "radio' is not a tag you can target  it as $("input[name=socPlan]")

$("input[name=socPlan]").blur(ValidateRadioButtons); works with your current code

Comment: No worries.. Anytime...

Answer (score 2):

I have implemented a different way to do this. take a look http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/eb4s1k11/

code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mybtn').on('click', function(){
        var test = $('[name="socPlan"]').is(':checked');
        alert(test);
    });
});
```

so you have stored in `test` if it's checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

Well you are not really on the right path here, you are mixing up stuff. Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vL9jvwe7/1/

```
 $planSelectValid = false;

    $('input').click(function () {  //Function for Validating If Radio Button isselected

    $('.socPlanRadios').find('radio').each(function () {  //LoopingthroughradioButtons
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

            $planSelectValid = true; 

        }
    });

    if ($planSelectValid = true) {
        alert("Validation Passed");

      } else {
        alert("Please select a Radio Button");
      }
    })
```